# How to access TenantId, ClientId, Secret etc.. in dot net core from Azure.Identity?

Tags: mongodb, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity

I have a dot net core web app deployed to Azure app service, with a System Managed Identity enabled.

I need to access the tenant id, client id and secret etc from within my code .. so I can pass them to a 3rd part library (mongodb client side field level encryption with key vault).

Is there any way to access these variables from within my code when using the Azure.Identity library?

I can use  `new DefaultAzureCredential()` - but I do not know how to access tenant ID etc.. from this object once it it instantiated?

Thanks!

Update - Mongodb Library code from https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/security/client-side-field-level-encryption-local-key-to-kms/#specify-the-azure-credentials

```
var kmsProviders = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>>();

var azureTenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FLE_AZURE_TENANT_ID");
var azureClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FLE_AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
var azureClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FLE_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");
var azureKmsOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "tenantId", azureTenantId },
    { "clientId", azureClientId },
    { "clientSecret", azureClientSecret },
};

kmsProviders.Add("azure", azureKmsOptions);
```

UPDATE: Workaround using Keyvault to get Master key and storing locally to act as a local provider for Mongo Driver..

// Pull the master key from Keyvault and add to local configuration

```
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                  var builtConfig = config.Build();
              
                if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction() && builtConfig["SystemConfig:UseKeyVault"] == "true")
                    {
                        Uri kvUri = new(builtConfig["SystemConfig:KeyVaultUri"]);

                        var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                            kvUri,
                            new DefaultAzureCredential());

                        // Add all settings from keyvault to config
                        config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());

                    }

                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

// Access key and store as local provider..

```
  private static Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> GetLocalKmsProvider(IOptions<MongoDbConfig> configuration)
        {
            var localMasterKey = Convert.FromBase64String(configuration.Value.MasterKey);
            var localKey = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "key", localMasterKey }
            };

            var kmsProviders = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>>();
            kmsProviders.Add("local", localKey);
            return kmsProviders;
        }
```

Comment: this is the point of using managed identity: you dont access credentials. what are you trying to achieve ? why do you need to pass this credentials?

Comment: Trying to pass the credentials in to 3rd part library.. see https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/security/client-side-field-level-encryption-local-key-to-kms/#specify-the-azure-credentials

Comment: So the keys are stored in KV ? could you share the code you have so far. you should be able to instantiate a kv client without having to specify credetnials but not sure if the mongo driver allow that.

Comment: The mongo library handles the KV client part.. that's why it needs the credentials. Its sends the datakeys stored in the DB to be decrypted by the master key stored in KV.  I am just using a local key for now until I get this working with KV. Added sample code to main question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so you cant retrieve the managed identity client_secret. I'll check if there is way to instantiate the Kv client using managed identity tho.

Comment: Thanks a mil. I am able to use KV client with managed ID for other settings no problem, but they are all using defaultAzureCredential().

Comment: Gave it a try but it doesnt seems to be possible. not familiar with the mongo documentation. If you can find some extension point where you could create your own prvider or extend the existing one it should be fpossible i guess.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll give Mongo forums a go.

Comment: One thing i was thinking, you could get the azure keyvault key using managed identity then specify local for the kms provider ?

Comment: Actually yes - that's exactly what I do now.. I pull the master key from KV and just store locally for the session and mongo just sees it as local provider. But I was hoping to get KV remote decrypt working. I have post on mongo forums - so I'll update this question if I get an answer.

Comment: you can post your workaround as an answer as well